# Client side Javascript assigning the default Static values to UserName and Email

Tags: javascript

Hi I worte a js client side and rendered that server side aswell when i user filling the form the Username field need to be simultaneously filled based on Email input before submiting the form.
My query is in the Email field and Username field the values "UserName"
and "Email" are appearing by Default and also i cant edit the email field the forms is able to submit with valuse UserName and Email which is not i am looking.
the below code is my client side JS

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" onkeyup="change();"></asp:TextBox>
function change(){
            document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_UserName').value = 'UserName';
            document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_Email').value = 'Email';
        UserName.value=Email.value;
         }
```

The below is my C# which i used stringbuilder

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {

System.Text.StringBuilder sb2 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb2.AppendLine(@"<script language='javascript'>");
sb2.AppendLine(@"function change(){");
sb2.AppendLine(@"var Email= document.getElementById('#ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_Email');");
sb2.AppendLine(@"var UserName= document.getElementById('#ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_UserName');");
sb2.AppendLine(@"UserName.value=Email.value;");
sb2.AppendLine(@" }");
sb2.Append(@"</script>");

if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", sb2.ToString());

}
```

The reason i added my code into C# stringbuilder is i am unable to get the java code on clientside when checked using f12 i am not able to see any of the java code which i wrote on aspx page so i used string builder to get that code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue.
I have used the below code

```
function change() {
            var Email = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_Email');
            var UserName = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_UserName');
            UserName.value = Email.value;
        }

System.Text.StringBuilder sb2 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb2.AppendLine(@"<script language='javascript'>");
            sb2.AppendLine(@"function change(){");
            sb2.AppendLine(@"var Email = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_Email');");
            sb2.AppendLine(@"var UserName = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_e7fed4bf_b25a_4a8a_943d_e31932556a9e_FBACreateUserWizard_CreateUserStepContainer_UserName');");
            sb2.AppendLine(@"UserName.value=Email.value;");
            sb2.AppendLine(@" }");
            sb2.AppendLine(@"</script>");
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
            {
               Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", sb2.ToString());

            }
```

Thanks